# Finding files with a certain string

Tags: php, windows, unix

I'm a real noob here. I was wondering if anyone could give me a piece of code that will find all files in a certain directory and that directory's subdirectories with the user-specified string. And if possible limit filetypes to be searched e.g. `*.php`

I'm 99% it's possible maybe using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, `preg_match` or `GLOB` but i'm really new to php and have next-to-no knowledge on these functions.

This kind of code is certainly easy to do with `UNIX` commands but PHP i'm kind of stuck (need PHP not unix solutions). Would appreciate all and every help I can get from you guys!

EDIT: Seems i might have confused some of you. I want that string to be INSIDE the file not to be in the FILENAME.

Comment: Are you on Windows server or Unix server? You tagged both.

Comment: See if it helps: http://www.redips.net/php/find-files-with-php/

Comment: I'm on unix but i just want to make sure that i need them to work on both i.e. a PHP solution

Answer (score 11):

You can accomplish this pretty easily.

```
// string to search in a filename.
$searchString = 'myFile';

// all files in my/dir with the extension 
// .php 
$files = glob('my/dir/*.php');

// array populated with files found 
// containing the search string.
$filesFound = array();

// iterate through the files and determine 
// if the filename contains the search string.
foreach($files as $file) {
    $name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    // determines if the search string is in the filename.
    if(strpos(strtolower($name), strtolower($searchString))) {
         $filesFound[] = $file;
    } 
}

// output the results.
print_r($filesFound);
```

Comment: Structure looking good but I get :  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /usr/www/virtual/myfile.php on line 21. Also, does this search recursively? I'm looking to search all subdirectories of the defined directory

Comment: Whoops, forgot a closing parentheses - updated the answer. No this implementation does not search recursively.

Comment: When I execute, i get output: Array ( )

Comment: Sorry, forgot to make the filename lowercase. It should work now assuming your search string exists in the directory you're searching.

Comment: Hmm, weird. when i search something with one word+ e.g. "extension" it outputs Array ( ) but when i searched for string "a" it outputs fine :s

Comment: What does the directory structure look like? And what string are you searching for?

Comment: The dir looks like:

/usr/www/virtual/1/
/usr/www/virtual/2/
/usr/www/virtual/3/a/
/usr/www/virtual/4/


my file is "/usr/www/virtual/4/index.php" and my directory defined is "/usr/www/virtual/4/" and the string i definied for was "extension(" in the file it is like "when my extension('...') is overlooked etc. etc."

Comment: I had to add !== false in my if... `if (strpos(strtolower($name), strtolower($searchString)) !== false)` now it works... ty

Answer (score 3):

Only tested on FreeBSD...

Find `string` within all files from a passed directory (*nix only):

```
<?php

$searchDir = './';
$searchString = 'a test';

$result = shell_exec('grep -Ri "'.$searchString.'" '.$searchDir);

echo '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>';

?>
```

Find `string` within all files from a passed directory using only PHP (not recommended on a large list of files):

```
<?php

$searchDir = './';
$searchExtList = array('.php','.html');
$searchString = 'a test';

$allFiles = everythingFrom($searchDir,$searchExtList,$searchString);

var_dump($allFiles);

function everythingFrom($baseDir,$extList,$searchStr) {
    $ob = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($baseDir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($ob as $name => $object){
        if (is_file($name)) {
            foreach($extList as $k => $ext) {
                if (substr($name,(strlen($ext) * -1)) == $ext) {
                    $tmp = file_get_contents($name);
                    if (strpos($tmp,$searchStr) !== false) {
                        $files[] = $name;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
?>
```

Edit: Corrections based on more details.

Comment: im sorry but where do I enter my string?

Comment: You need to pass in the `string` to `everythingFrom('./','.php');` So, replace `'./'` with `string`. (the example is searching the current `basedir` which is `./`) Edit: answer updated to make it clearer.

Comment: is it using the current directory as defined directory? i was looking for something like $directory = '/var/www/' $searchString = 'mystring'; etc.

Comment: OK, made some changes to the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Ok, i just tested. when I have $searchString = 'a'; it just returns all files/dirs/subdirs in my defined dir. when I have $searchString = 'myotherproperstring' it returns "NULL", even though the string is in the file in the proper dir. one thing i noticed though when using $searchString = 'a'; is that it is looking in all subdirectories, which is good. not sure why it's not recognizing proper strings though :S p.s. the new code searches all filetypes, not just *.php?

Comment: When you say 'even though the string is in the file', if you mean 'within the file' then this function will *not* work. If you mean 'within the file name' then this function will work. If you are search for a string within a file, you need to use something else, which I only know a Unix solution for.

Comment: oh...yeah i'm looking for a certain string INSIDE the file

Comment: yeah man, I know how to execute using unix commands but i'm looking solely for a PHP solution without command executing e.g system and grep

Comment: Edit: You could use `strpos` on each file, but it would be system heavy if you have a lot of files to search.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! mate, no matter for the speed this is working :) could you please add it so maybe I can search only 1 or few extensions e.g. *.php and *.html

Comment: Oh, may i know why it is not recommended to run often? p.s. 1 LAST request if you don't mind, when the script searches for a string e.g. "extension_loaded" can the first line of the file found with the string be showing along side the line e.g. "/usr/www/virtual/index.php : hello, my name is extension_loaded"? It is not a necessity but would be awesome if it is possible! Thanks a lot man! p.s. i tried upvoting you but i need 15 rep :/ sorry

Answer (score 2):

I found a small file to search the string from folder:

Download file [from](https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles) here.